# Seg fault using struct

Tags: c, concatenation

I have been writing C for approximately a week, so bear with me. I'm getting a segmentation fault error in the method `assemble_url` and I dont know why. Here is my code:

```
/** Includes */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>

/** Definitions */
#define MAX_OPTIONS 32
#define MAX_ARGS 32

/** Command option */
typedef struct {
    char *argname;
    char *value;
} command_option;

/** Command */
typedef struct {
    command_option options[MAX_OPTIONS];
} command_t;

/**
 * Prints the arguments passed in in a hashmap format (key => value)
 */
void populate_command(command_t *cmd,int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int i,j=0;

    /** Check to see if we have arguments. If argc is equal to 1 than there are no arguments besides the filename */
    if(argc>1)
    {

        /* Start at position 1, since argv[0] is the filename being called */
        for(i=1;i<argc;i++)
        {

            /* Head of argv array */
            char *arg = argv[i];

            /* Create a copy of head for traversal. */
            char *c = arg;

            /* traverse the char array, ensuring we arent dealing with NULL values(c!==NULL) and NULL pointers(*c!=='\0') */
            while(*c != '\0' && c != NULL)
            {

                /* Were only concerned with parsing the flags and obtaining the flag value. */
                if(strchr("-",*c))
                {

                    char *key = c; /* Key */
                    char *value = argv[i+1]; /* Value */

                    /* ensure we have a value existent for key */
                    if(strchr("-",*value))
                    {
                        /** user supplied a key with no value */
                        break;
                    }
                    command_option *option = &cmd->options[j];
                    option->argname = key;
                    option->value   = value;

                    j++;

                    /* Debug dump */
                    printf("arg %d: %s -> %s\n",i,option->argname,option->value);

                }/* end strchr */

                /** Increment the traversal array */
                c++;

            }/* end while loop */

        }/* end forloop */

    }/* endif */

}/** end print_args */

/**
 * Concatenates two strings and returns the resulting concatenated string
 */
char* concatstring(char *s1,char *s2)
{
    /* Allocate memory for *result. We add 1 to account for the extra byte to store the null character. Strlen accounts for all
     non-null bytes, so using strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1 ensures that an overflow wont occur. An overflow occurs when
     the number of bytes being used (in our example, is the addition of strlen for s1 and s2) is more than the number of bytes
     allocated (in our example, the number of bytes allocated to *result)*/
    char *result = malloc(strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1);

    /*Copies the C string pointed by source(s1) into the array pointed by destination(result), including the terminating null character. */
    strcpy(result,s1);

    /* appends a copy of the source string(s2) to the destination string(result). The terminating null character in
     destination is overwritten by the first character of source, and a null-character is included at
     the end of the new string formed by the concatenation of both in destination.*/
    strcat(result,s2);

    /* return result */
    return result;

} /** end concatstring */

char* assemble_url(command_t *cmd,char *str)
{
    int i,opt_len = sizeof(&cmd->options);
    for(i=0;i<opt_len;i++)
    {
        command_option *option = &cmd->options[i];
        char *key = option->argname;
        char *value = option->value;
        if(i==0)
        {
            str = concatstring(str,key);
            str = concatstring(str,"=");
            str = concatstring(str,value);
        }
        else
        {
            str = concatstring(str,"&");
            str = concatstring(str,key);
            str = concatstring(str,"=");
            str = concatstring(str,value);
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

What occurs in this program is the following:

1./ User types in program name and flag options,such as the following:
 `program -test a -test2 b`

2./ The program parses the command and populates a command struct with options. Each option has a flag(argname) and value associated to it(value)

3./ The program then tries to create a URL with those option keys and values, such as `http://url/?test=a&test2=b`

The program compiles but I'm still new to pointers and references (I think & is called a reference), so maybe that is why the program errors.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Also, if you see any probems or better way to handle assemble_url, please also let me know (I dont think its being handled in the best way, but like I said, I'm extremely new to C programming)

Thanks!

Comment: Now is a good time to learn how to use a debugger. It will help you pinpoint the location of the crash, will let you examine the function call stack, and also let you examine variable to help you figure out the possible cause of the crash.

Comment: Are you aware just how much this code leaks memory? The chained `str = concatstring(str,...)` calls may be something you want to consider rethinking, among other things.

Comment: I updated the content. The program compiles fine with assemble_url uncommented. I am not sure how to use a debugger.

Comment: Absiolutely. I dont know another way to handle assemble_url, so this is a call for assistance in the segfault and also fixing up assemble_url

Comment: Updated content to ask for help with assemble_url

Comment: Like @JoachimPileborg says, you should learn to use a debugger.  If you cannot debug, you cannot develop software.  The issue of sizeof(&something), as posted by AndreyT, would have been obvious when inspecting the values with a debugger.

Comment: How abt adding one more field to struct to maintain the count of no. of commands added so far. Will that help ?

Answer (score 1):

This initialization

```
int opt_len = sizeof(&cmd->options);
```

will give you the byte-size of a pointer `&cmd->options`. This makes no sense in the context of what you are trying to do.

If you want to determine the number of elements in an array (assuming it hasn't decayed to pointer), the proper technique would be

```
int opt_len = sizeof cmd->options / sizeof *cmd->options;
```

In this case `opt_len` will be initialized with `MAX_OPTIONS` value (meaning that you can just use `MAX_OPTIONS` in its place).

Comment: How do I get the length of the size of the options array then?

Comment: i still get a seg fault after fixing that.

Comment: @jkushner: Of course, you do. You only initialize `argc` elements of the array in `populate_command`. Why are you trying to process all `MAX_OPTIONS` of them later in `assemble_url`? If you initialized `argc` elements, then only use `argc` elements in `assemble_url`.

Comment: @jkushner that `j` would be a pretty handy thing to remember when you're done processing your options list, you know, just in case you want to walk back over the options created at some future time and ou need to know when to *stop*.

Comment: I changed it to argc and Im still getting a seg fault. I dont know how to use a debugger yet, and I'll learn that this week, but for the meantime any help would be greatly appreciated. @WhozCraig I see what you are saying. You think I should pass j into `assemble_url`?

Comment: @jkushner I think your `command_t` type, which currently only holds at-most MAX_OPTIONS number of options, would be well served to have an additional member, `count` that specifies how *many* options are actually "valid". Starting it at 0 and incrementing *it* as you add options, would be a good idea. From there, any consumers of the `command_t` struct will *know* how many options [0..(count-1)] are actually "valid".

Answer (score 1):

You have massive memory leaks from concatstring. Each invocation allocates a new buffer but you never bother to free them, and you loose the pointers so no chance of ever freeing that memory again.

This is not the cause of the segfault.

Comment: Can you assist with programming concat_string?

Comment: Just create a long buffer, say 1024 bytes and append stuff to it (and check for size problems all the time). If the size is exceeded you can realloc() or return an error condition.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are concatenating more than two strings it would be best if you allocated memory for all concatenations at once.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string>
char* stringBuilder(int count, ...)
{
    va_list ap, vacnt;
    int j;
    int len = 1;
    char* buffer;
    va_start(ap, count); 
#ifdef va_copy
        va_copy(vacnt,ap);
#else
    vacnt = ap;
#endif
    for(j=0; j<count; ++j){
        len+=strlen(va_arg(vacnt, char*)); 
    }
    va_end(vacnt);
    buffer = (char*) malloc(len * sizeof(char));
    buffer[0]=0;
    for (j=0;j<count;++j) {
       strcat (buffer, va_arg(ap, char*));
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return buffer;
 }
```

You can use it as such:

```
char* x = stringBuilder(4,"hello", " ", "world", "\n");
printf(x);
free(x);
```

Also note that both key and value must be URL-Encoded for the purposes of your application